# How to run old versions of Safari on Mac OS Mountain Lion?

Tags: safari

I am testing some website for cross-browser support, but mac OS does not support older versions of safari once you updated you system.

How can I run old Safari on mac OS Mountain Lion?

[Like here](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/) but there are no newer versions and some of them doesnt run on my OS as well.

Comment: +1 I'm in the same boat. Need to test Safari5 - some subtle styling details are different.

Answer (score 1):

It's not much help but there are services such as http://spoon.net/browsers/ that let you sandbox any browser you want. The downside is that you have to pay $12/mo. if you want to use the older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution here…as Safari 5.x uses RSS plumbing from Lion and earlier and is not in Mountain Lion (i.e. things that Safari 5.x needs to run successfully are not available at the OS level in Mountain Lion).